# concat last 07 days files into one file in Shell

Tags: linux, shell, date, cat

I have daily generate files with name like `ABC_20170622.csv` , only date parameter will be changed. I need to concat last 07 days files based on the date parameter into one file, this will be done on every Monday.

Sample file set;

`Jun 15 07:00 ABC_20170614.csv
Jun 16 07:00 ABC_20170615.csv
Jun 17 07:00 ABC_20170616.csv
Jun 18 07:00 ABC_20170617.csv
Jun 19 07:00 ABC_20170618.csv
Jun 20 07:00 ABC_20170619.csv
Jun 21 07:00 ABC_20170620.csv
Jun 22 07:00 ABC_20170621.csv
Jun 23 07:00 ABC_20170622.csv`

It's like
`cat ABC_20170619.csv ABC_20170620.csv ABC_20170621.csv > one_week.csv`

But I need to get the date automaticaly and this will be run in shell script..

Comment: Do you trust the mtimes to be accurate? If you don't need to go off names and trust the filesystem metadata, it's just `find . -mtime -7 -exec cat -- {} + >one_week.csv`

Comment: BTW -- can you use bash builtins for this? If so, which version? (Modern bash -- since 4.2 or so -- has `printf %()T` format string support making the `date` command unnecessary in some cases).

Comment: And if you *don't* have modern bash, are you guaranteed to have a GNU implementation of `date` (as opposed to the busybox one, or a BSD version, or such)?

Comment: Bash version is `2.05b.0(1)-release` , for above code, I'm getting error as `missing argument to `-exec'`

Comment: 2.05b?! That's almost unbelievably ancient. I don't think I've seen anything older than 3.2 (itself a decade old) in *years*.

Comment: so, if your `find` is as old as your `bash`, you'd probably need `find . -mtime -7 -exec cat -- {} \;`; support for `{} +` was added to POSIX around 2008 or so (even though GNU had it long before that), and your toolchain is much older than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First -- the *easy* thing is to use file timestamps, not names. That would look like:

```
find . -mtime -7 -exec cat -- {} + >one_week.csv
```

But let's say you really *do* need to use names. Okay, then:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }

[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || die "This script requires bash"
[[ $BASH_VERSION =~ ^[0123] ]] && die "This script requires bash 4.2"
[[ $BASH_VERSION =~ ^4[.][01][.] ]] && die "This script requires bash 4.2"

# bash 4.2: get current epoch time in seconds
printf -v current_time_seconds '%(%s)T' -1

# subtract 7 days from that
prev_week_seconds=$(( current_time_seconds - (60 * 60 * 24 * 7) ))

# convert it to YYYYMMDD
printf -v prev_week_date '%(%Y%m%d)T' "$prev_week_seconds"

# generate the first name that matches
start_file=ABC_${prev_week_date}.csv

# generate an array listing files that exist with that name or newer
files=( )
for f in ABC_*.csv; do
  if [[ $f = $start_file || $f > $start_file ]]; then
    files+=( "$f" )
  fi
done

# concatenate all files generated above
cat -- "${files[@]}" >one_week.csv
```

If you need to make this work with older versions of bash (err, *reasonably* older versions of bash -- I'm not guaranteeing anything pre-3.2), change `printf -v current_time_seconds '%(%s)T' -1` to `current_time_seconds=$(date +%s)`, and `printf -v prev_week_date '%(%Y%m%d)T' "$prev_week_seconds"` to `prev_week_date=$(date -d "@$prev_week_seconds" +%Y%m%d)`. Note that even these require GNU date, and are not guaranteed to work with `date` commands provided by other OS vendors.